Gitlab CE : Background Migrations : BackfillMergeRequest stuck at 41% after upgrade from 16.7.3 to 16.7.7

I upgraded our gitlab docker from current version of 16.7.3 to 16.7.7. Upgrade was fine and most of the functionalities are working as expected.
however I see this issue where
Background Migrations : BackfillMergeRequestDiffsProjectId: merge_request_diffs stuck at 41% after upgrade from 16.7.3 to 16.7.7[gitlab-ui-migration-jobs]
And when I looks into db, this is what I see

SELECT
 id,
 job_class_name,
 table_name,
 column_name,
 job_arguments
FROM batched_background_migrations
WHERE status <> 3;

gitlabhq-> WHERE status <> 3;
 id  |           job_class_name           |     table_name      | column_name | job_arguments
-----+------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------
 172 | BackfillMergeRequestDiffsProjectId | merge_request_diffs | id          | []
(1 row)

So when I try to upgrade it, gitlab complains about finalized job not in finished stage.
StateMachines::InvalidTransition: Cannot transition status via :finish from :finalizing (Reason(s): Batched jobs jobs need to be succeeded)

I marked them completed by updating
UPDATE batched_background_migration_jobs
SET status = '4
WHERE batched_background_migration_id = (172);


UPDATE batched_background_migration_jobs
SET status = '4'
WHERE batched_background_migration_id = (SELECT id FROM batched_background_migrations WHERE job_class_name = 'FinalizeMergeRequestDiffsProjectIdBackfill');

It may be the case that one migration job was running while tried to upgrade to next version and there are few rows in table
merge_request_diffs 

which has project ids as NULL which has NOT_NULL constraint.
So if I try to upgrade, gitlab errors out with
PG::CheckViolation: ERROR:  check constraint "check_11c5f029ad" of relation "merge_request_diffs" is violated by some row

Is there anyway I can run few commands which can finish the migration?
I did run below command but that does not really do anything.
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake "gitlab:background_migrations:finalize[BackfillMergeRequestDiffsProjectId, 'merge_request_diffs', 'id', [] ]" --trace RAILS_ENV=production

